# OpenCV Camera Not working in android Samsung s2

Tags: android, opencv, mobile, camera

I am using **OpenCV Library 2.4.3** JavaCameraView to open Camera. I have using sample project **"OpenCV Image Manipulation"** which is provided with the openCV Library. *App is working fine in Samsung S3 , S4* even micromax ninja, but app will **display only blank screen** (Black) when i run app **in Samsung S2 or Micromax HD**

Can you please tell me why it is happening, it is any bug in OpenCV library or this is any other problem

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I had similar trouble with an opencv app that suddenly stopped working on my S2 when there was an auto install of opencv manager. I went back to the version that comes with the opencv android sdk (version 2.9 I think it was) although 2.16 seems to be ok on my S2 now.

Answer (score 0):

You downgrade the opencv library SDK in android project  i moved from 2.4.7 to 2.4.3 and it worked fine it now showing camera now